# Audio play/pause on different button click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

This is a simple query but somehow i can't seem to put a finger to what seems to be going wrong.

I have two buttons namely 'problem' and 'need'. On clicking the former, the audio file 1 needs to be played, similarly when later is clicked the audio file 1 should stop and audio file 2 is played. The code which i have written for the same is this:

```
var playing = false;

$("#problem").click(function(event) {
    $("#audio").html('');
    $("#audio").html('<source src="audio/expertise/file1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><source src="audio/expertise/file1.wav" type="audio/x-wav"><source src="audio/expertise/file1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">');
    playing = true;
});

$('.need_btn').attr('id', 'need_btn');

$("#need_btn").click(function(event) {
    if (playing == true) {
        $("#audio").trigger('pause');
        playing = false;

        if (playing == false){

            $("#audio").attr('src','<source src="audio/expertise/file2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.wav" type="audio/x-wav"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">');
            $("#audio").trigger('play');
            playing = true;
        };
    }
    else{
        /*$("#audio").trigger('play');*/
        };
});
```

this works fine for playing file 1 , pause file 1 when second button is clicked but does not play file 2. 
What can i change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is this piece of code:

```
 $("#audio").attr('src','<source src="audio/expertise/file2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.wav" type="audio/x-wav"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">');
```

I just went through the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and it seems like you are using the `.attr` in an incorrect way. I haven't tried the code I'm going to post, but assuming you do want to set the attributes of the `source` element, you might want to try something on these lines:

```
 $( "source" ).attr({
 src: "audio/expertise/file2.mp3",
 type: "audio/mp3"
 });
```

Now I understand you have the `.ogg` , `.wav` and the `.mp3` versions. So I think it's also possible you directly set the `html` for the element with id "audio" like you did with `file1`. I'm suggesting something like this:

```
 $("#audio").html('<source src="audio/expertise/file2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.wav" type="audio/x-wav"><source src="audio/expertise/file2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">');
```

This would set the `html` for the corresponding element with the required markup. I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for sharing the correct syntax for the .attr
that helped in solving the query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on jquery but in the end I inserted this js code:

```
document.querySelector('.farm-play-btn').addEventListener("click", function () {
    let vid = this.previousElementSibling;
    vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();
});
```